# integration of Android with servlet or mysql database

Tags: java, android, mysql

I have made school management software...for the server side I have designed the admin panel using servlet and jsp technology.and have used mysql database and for the client I have created an Android app. I want to perform login and logout authentication and fetch data of that particular user on his app.. but I m unable to integrate. I need to know what are ways through which this thing is done professionally.... 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

At your backend side you have your servlet which handles incoming requests GET or POST. So in android app you just need to make call to your servlet and handle the response.
In android
1. Get the user credentials and pass it along with your request.Either make GET request and append your credentials to servlet url or pass the parameters as POST request.
2. To make network calls use libraries such as **Volley**, **Retrofit** or you can even use android built-in **AsyncTask**.(If you are a beginner start with AsyncTask first and then upgrade to libraries mentioned).

**Professional way is to develop REST apis at your backend and call them from your android app.**